# How to get info from terminal in python

Tags: python-3.x

I use `ytapi` to get info from searching a YouTube video and I get a videoId in terminal. So i am trying to get that so from that i can open the YouTube video.

Here is what i've done:

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build

youtube = build("youtube" , "v3" , developerKey = api_key)

req = youtube.search().list(q="google",part="id",type="video",fields="items/id")
res = req.execute()

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'items': [{'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'XKmsYB54zBk'}}, {'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'd6nwLctqB3c'}}, {'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'F95wcsJAz0c'}}, {'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'p0ysH2Glw5w'}}, {'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'GvmDVq3PtA8'}}]}
```

From that is there a way to get only the videoId so i can use it to open videos with

```
webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= " + videoId)
```

Comment: You don't need to read from the terminal with this. You are actually trying to read from the 'res' variable, which is a dictionary with lists of dictionaries inside of it. You need to look into how to access dictionaries and lists in python. This is core python stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

youtube = build("youtube" , "v3" , developerKey = api_key)

req = youtube.search().list(q="google",part="id",type="video",fields="items/id") 
res = req.execute()

urladd = res['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= " + urladd)
```